# automatically tab to the next input field in cells of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want to automatically tab to the next `input` field when reaching the `maxlength` of each field. Each input field is placed in a `cell` of a `table`.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="td1202">
<tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
        <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
        <td class="decimal">,</td>
        <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
        <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
        <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I've tried this so far:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
 if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
$(this)
  .blur()
  .parent()
  .next()
  .children('input')
  .focus();
}
});
```

Comment: try changing `maxLength` to `maxlength` same way you have it in the attribute. Beyond that you didn't specify what is or isn't happening and you will also need to work out the gap and jumping to next row also

Comment: I changed to 'maxlength' and it still didn't work.
My problem is also exactly what you mentioned, skip the gap and jump to next row.

Comment: Hey!! `maxLength` is the correct JS property name... [See here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bjjvGQ?editors=1011)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Your code was not working because you have `<td class="decimal">,</td>` and due to which your code is not able to find the next `input` children so it stops working after first two inputs. Your code will work if `<td class="decimal">,</td>` is not there.

**Solution:**

Instead of checking child etc you can you can simply find the index of next input.

Below is working example:

```js
$("input").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    var index = $(this).index("input");
    $("input:eq(" + (index + 1) + ")").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="td1202">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
      <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
      <td class="decimal">,</td>
      <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
      <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
      <td><input maxlength="1" type="text" style="width: 20px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks a million bro. 
But I still don't get why my code doesn't work and how to fix my own code.

Comment: @vic: You should remove the *«Firstly»* assumption you made, because it's false. Then OP asks for more explanation. Which would be a good thing.

Comment: @VicJordan: nice explanation!